# Non-Isomorphic Groups generated by a Set of fixed cardinaity

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Given a set of permutations $A \subset S_n$. It has $|A|$ (the [cardinality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardinality) of $A$) elements.
 We can construct a group using $A$.

How many non-isomorphic groups(all with the same order) can we construct with the generating set $A$ when $|A|$ is constant (the number of elements in generating set is fixed)?

Comment: Groups of same order are related to conjugacy class.

Comment: So you want the number $f(l,m,n)$ of isomorphism classes of $l$-generator subgroups of $S_n$ of order $m$? There will not be any kind of simple formula for this, and it will not be easy to compute for $n$ bigger than about $10$, so what are you really looking for?

Comment: @DerekHolt  you are correct. No, I am not looking for anything else. Would you suggest me a survey paper related to the problem based on some specific cases?. Thanks for the comment.

Comment: Sorry but I do not know of any existing literature on this particular problem, and I am very sceptical about whether it is possible to say anything much about it in that generality. There may be interesting special cases like $m=n$, when you are just asking for the number of $l$-generator groups of order $n$.